# For Tomcat 6, is context.xml for my webapp required to be in $catalina_base/conf/?

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, tomcat6

Reading through the documentation on Apache Tomcat, when I deploy a webapp it copies the `webapp/META-INF/context.xml` to `$catalina_base/conf/{engine}/{host}/{webapp}.xml.`

However, in server.xml I have set Hosts to have deployXML=false and would like to read context.xml file from straight from webapp/META-INF/context.xml.

Is that possible or is it required that it be at `$catalina_base/{engine}/{host}/{webapp}.xml?` If possible, what property\setting\attribute am I missing since it seems to not read in from `webapp/META-INF/context.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html): if you set deployXML to false you disable parsing of the webapp/META-INF/context.xml and require the context.xml files to be in conf.

Change deployXML to true and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping that it could be read straight from webapp/META-INF/context.xml. Is it required to be read from /conf/?

EDIT: I think I might have misread, doesn't deployXML automatically copy to the /conf/ folder? I would like it to just not exist in that folder.

Comment: Well, it CAN be read from `webapp/META-INF/context.xml`, but you HAVE to set deployXML to true. If you choose to set deployXML to false, then it will NOT read from `webapp/META-INF/context.xml`.

Comment: Sorry misunderstanding. If you set deployXML to true, then all it does is copy webapp/META-INF/context.xml to the /conf/ folder. This is what I don't want.

Comment: Ah, I did misunderstand: you want to parse `webapp/META-INF/context.xml` but not have Tomcat copy it? That isn't possible, sorry to say. The rule is that the context.xml is parsed from conf, but you can chose whether or not to allow it to be copied.